# initdb: could not change permissions of directory on Postgresql container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am new to the docker ecosystem and I am trying to spin up a simple postgres container along with a volume so it persists its data, by using a yaml composer file. The file is as follows:

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.3'
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: recrow
            POSTGRES_USER: recrow
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: recrow_db_1000
            PGDATA: /var/lib/pgsql/data/pgdata
        volumes:
          - ./pgsql/data:/var/lib/pgsql/data/pgdata
```

However, upon calling `docker-compose -f stack.yml up` I get the following error:

> fixing permissions on existing directory
>   /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ... initdb: could not change
>   permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata": Operation
>   not permitted

`/var/lib/pgsql/data/pgdata` is supposed to be a directory relative to the container's root, while `./pgsql/data` is a path on the host. I am running the container from an ntfs-3g partition mounted on `/mnt/storage`. What could be the problem? I am also running docker without root permissions, by adding my user to the docker group and this user also has full access to the beforementioned mount point `/mnt/storage`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing this is going to be an incompatibility with ntfs-3g. The PostgreSQL image contains an entrypoint script that is doing some permission changes on container start: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/972294a377463156c8d61297320c872fc7d370a9/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L32-L38. I found another relevant question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition that talks about being able to set permissions at mount time. But not being able to change via `chmod` or `chown` (which is likely the reason for the failure in this case).

Unfortunately, I think the answer here is that you cannot use ntfs-3g safely for backing Docker host volume mounts.

Comment: Any update on this in modern times with WSL or WSL 2?

Comment: I personally have not tried it. But WSL/WSL2 should natively support Linux permissions. If it isn't working and there is a problem that is probably a separate issue and warrants a separate question.

Comment: It works fine if I use a named volume but not if I use volumes: - ./pgsql/data:/var/lib/pgsql/data/pgdata

Answer (score 8):

Following off of @liam-mitchell's note above, that is the answer. Use named volumes such like the following:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - "postgres:/data/postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGDATA=/data/postgres

...

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Answer (score 5):

I work with OpenShift and had the same problem to run this official image from Docker Hub.

In my case, the solution was to use the official postgres image from red hat repository, the image from red hat repository has fixed this problem, this is can be an alternative.

Comment: This comment should be a gem. In my case, I was using Jhipster to deploy to Openshift. 
After I changed the Postgres image to one from the Redhat Repository I also had to change the following environment variable names in the deployment config (that was generated by JHipster).

POSTGRES_USER  to POSTGRESQL_USER
POSTGRES_PASSWORD to POSTGRESQL_PASSWOD
POSTGRES_DATABASE to POSTGRESQL_DATABASE

basically, I appended QL onto POSTGRES.

Comment: Here are some of the images: https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with docker on WSL2. Setting the :Z flag for the mount and **not mounting to a Windows file system directory (`/mnt/*`) but a linux directory (`/home/*`)** worked for me.

my compose:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
    postgres:
        container_name: dbs2-postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        volumes:
            - './data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z'
        image: postgres
```

Comment: Thanks! Just using the Linux directory without ":Z" worked for me 