# Helm Sentry installation failed on deployment: initdb: could not change permissions of directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, sentry, kubernetes-helm

I have a local Openshift instance where I'm trying to install Sentry using helm as:

`helm install --name sentry --wait stable/sentry`.

All pods are deployed fine other than the `PostgreSQL` pod also deployed as a dependency for Sentry. 
This pod's initiliazation fails as a `CrashLoopBackOff` and the logs show the following:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata": Operation not permitted
```

Not sure where to start to fix this issue so I can get sentry deployed successfully with all its dependencies

Comment: What file system do you use on the volumes? Look at this reported [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878062/initdb-could-not-change-permissions-of-directory-on-postgresql-container), maybe it can be helpful for you.

Comment: I have a similar problem https://serverfault.com/questions/941774/run-initdb-with-user-having-write-rights-but-not-owner-of-pgdata-directory , if you use OSE you can use RHEL images https://docs.okd.io/latest/using_images/db_images/postgresql.html , but otherwise we need to replicate the steps that RedHat has made (which I'm trying out to figure).

Comment: @9ilsdx 9rvj 0lo Look below and see if that resolves your issue

Comment: @shanwar no, disabling security settings is not a solution, it is a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by adding permissions to the service account that was being used to run commands on the pod.
In my case the default service account on OpenShift was being used.
I added the appropriate permissions to this service account using the cli:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default --as system:admin
```

Also see: https://blog.openshift.com/understanding-service-accounts-sccs/

Comment: Workaround and not a full fledged solution